How to query and table data whose one of column data type is TYPE object and i want the value from the same column
I have a customer table whose CUST_ADDRESS column is a TYPE as OBJECT
Customer Table DDL
CUST_ADDRESS_TYP structure
I want the value of city from the CUST_ADDRESS_TYP which is subset of CUST_ADDRESS column in my CUSTOMER table.
please help me to write the query for above result.
Not able to write the correct query

A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. And show us your current query attempt. Also, use properly formatted text, not images (or links to them.)

[Edit] your question to include your DDL as text (not image). Also provide enough sample data and the desired result to illustrate your task (also as text).

Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the DDL statements for a minimal example of your table and object as text (not an image); and the INSERT statements for your sample data; and the expected output.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can use table_alias.column_name.object_attribute to get the value (the table_name or table_alias is required before the column_name):
SELECT id,
       name,
       c.address.street,
       c.address.city
FROM   customer c

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TYPE address_type IS OBJECT(
  street VARCHAR2(20),
  city   VARCHAR2(20)
);

CREATE TABLE customer (
  id      NUMBER,
  name    VARCHAR2(20),
  address address_type
);

INSERT INTO customer (id, name, address)
VALUES (1, 'Alice', address_type('Somewhere Street', 'Random City'));

Outputs:



ID
NAME
ADDRESS.STREET
ADDRESS.CITY




1
Alice
Somewhere Street
Random City



fiddle
